# Understanding COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, compatibility

I understood that setting a database to a COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL prior to your native one prevented features from being used. However this doesn't seem to be the case. Witness the following SQL script:

```
CREATE DATABASE Foo
GO
USE Foo
GO
ALTER DATABASE Foo SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 80
GO

CREATE TABLE Bar
(
    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    TestNvcMax NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL, -- Arrived in SQL 2005
    TestDateTime2 DATETIME2 (7) NOT NULL -- Arrived in SQL 2008
)
GO
```

But this table creates perfectly - any ideas? I would have thought some kind of an error message or warning would have been appropriate

Comment: Same phenomena occurs with `select ... offset ... fetch` syntax running well under a 100 (2008) compatibility level on SQL Server 2012, while this was introduced in 2012. I was really having bad assumptions on what does compatibility level.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you can read about the differences between compatibility level 80, 90 and 100. [ALTER DATABASE Compatibility Level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx)

Apparently new data types is not affected. I think that compatibility level is there to make SQL Server "behave" like the older version, not prevent you from doing new fancy stuff.

Comment: "Apparently new data types is not affected" To be fair, it doesn't explicitly say that (I had read that article prior to this posting) but I still think that it should function just like VS when I pick an older version of the .NET Framework. The new stuff just isn't available...

Comment: Awarding answer to Mikael as this appears closest to what's actually happening.

Answer (score 8):

[BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx) says:

> Compatibility level provides only
>   partial backward compatibility with
>   earlier versions of SQL Server.

Also:

> New functionality might work under
>   older compatibility levels, but SET
>   options might require adjustments.

I believe that is your case.

Comment: "but SET options might require adjustments." I'm not SETting anything. All I'm doing is table and sproc creation, which fails when I try to run the scripts on the target SQL 2000 machine...

Answer (score 3):

I understand this is an old post, but for anyone else who ends up here as I did, more information is always helpful.

It could also be that the new compatibility did not take effect before running the create table statement.

"The new compatibility setting for a database takes effect when a USE Database is issued or a new login is processed with that database as the default database."
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx)