# is there a way to show this SQL query on 1 line?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to show on 1 line my clients name and all of their check dates for the month of January in 2014. Some clients may have 5 check dates in the month while other may only have 1 or 3. Is there a way to make this happen? Using this SQL query:

```
SELECT CC.co, checkDate FROM CCalendar CC
    INNER JOIN CInfo CI on CC.co = CI.co 
WHERE checkDate BETWEEN '01/01/2014' AND '01/31/2014' 
    AND CI.endDate IS NULL AND CI.status IN ('LIVE', 'CONVERSION')
```

The results currently look like this:

```
co | checkDate
---+------------
co | 01/03/2014
co | 01/14/2014
co | 01/17/2014
co | 01/24/2014
co | 01/24/2014
```

and what I want it to look like is this

```
Co | checkdate1| checkdate2| checkdate3| checkdate4| checkdate5|
co | 01/03/2014| 01/14/2014| 01/17/2014| 01/24/2014| 01/24/2014|
```

Comment: Which check date do you want to show, if there *are* multiple values? The system doesn't *guess*

Comment: I would like to show all check dates within the month. some clients (very few) will have checkdates on the same date in cases where mngmt gets paid separately from other employees.

Comment: can you edit your question and show your expected results then? Your explanation isn't helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, What you need to use here is a combination of both [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

Your statment should be close to this:

```
SELECT co, [1] as checkDate1, [2] checkDate2, [3] checkDate3, [4] checkDate4, [5] checkDate5 FROM
(
SELECT CC.co, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CC.co ORDER BY CC.co) AS CheckDateNum, checkDate 
FROM CCalendar CC
    INNER JOIN CInfo CI on CC.co = CI.co 
WHERE checkDate BETWEEN '01/01/2014' AND '01/31/2014' 
    AND CI.endDate IS NULL AND CI.status IN ('LIVE', 'CONVERSION')
) AS T1

PIVOT (MAX(checkDate) for CheckDateNum in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) as checkDate
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: Please check this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624262/understanding-compatibility-level-in-sql-server) for the error. I've tested this on SQL Server 2008 R2. You might have to alter your compatibility level like this: 
`ALTER DATABASE database_name 
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100`

Comment: I got this working!!! Thank you! I'm trying to change the format of the date time to a standard us date IE 10/29/2013 and i keep getting errors. any clue where I would put that?

Answer (score 2):

You're what you're looking for is a  function similar to MySql's `group_concat` function, only in SQL Server instead.

This is probably a bad idea to do this in your query... instead, you should handle this in your UI / front-end, and build up your comma separated `checkDate` column there instead.

However, if you're still wanting to do this in your query, [this question's answers show how this can be done in SQL Server.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 0):

This will use the XML features of sql server to make a comma separated list of dates

```
SELECT CC.co,
  stuff((
    SELECT ',' + CAST(checkDate AS varchar(MAX))
    FROM CInfo CI
    WHERE CI.co = CC.co
     AND checkDate BETWEEN '01/01/2014' AND '01/31/2014' 
     AND CI.endDate IS NULL AND CI.status IN ('LIVE', 'CONVERSION') 
    for xml path('')
  ),1,1,'') as CheckDateList
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using CASE .. WHEN .. THEN .. ELSE .. END' syntax in [SQL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).

```
SELECT CC.co,

(case when ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CC.co) = 1 then checkDate end) as [checkDate1],

(case when ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CC.co) = 2 then checkDate end) as [checkDate2],

(case when ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CC.co) = 3 then checkDate end) as [checkDate3],

(case when ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CC.co) = 4 then checkDate end) as [checkDate4],

(case when ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CC.co) = 5 then checkDate end) as [checkDate5]

FROM CCalendar CC
    INNER JOIN CInfo CI on CC.co = CI.co 
WHERE checkDate BETWEEN '01/01/2014' AND '01/31/2014' 
    AND CI.endDate IS NULL AND CI.status IN ('LIVE', 'CONVERSION')
```

Comment: this looks like it will be what i need but i get this error: Invalid column name 'RowNum'.

Comment: How About replacing RowNum with ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CC.co). See updated SQL

Comment: i get this error Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate. not sure why though.

Comment: I think I know why you're getting this error message. if you you look at this [article](http://www.sqlerror.sqlserver-training.com/tag/windowed-functions-cannot-be-used-in-the-context-of-another-windowed-function-or-aggregate/) it explains why. I updated the query to reflect the solution. However, I  highly recommend my second solution (above or/ below) cause I tested it and it worked. Couldn't upload a picture that shows the result.