# SQL Server isdate check not working as expected

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

I'm getting an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time when converting from character string

with the following code:

```
select 
    case 
       when isdate('19' + left(somestring, 6)) = 1 
          then cast('19' + left(somestring, 6) as date) 
    end 
from 
    sometable
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Also, how would I go about seeing the string that's causing the error?

Comment: Can you show some sample data

Comment: The top 10 values of somestring in my example that don't give an error all start with '000101' and successfully convert to '1900-01-01'. Basically I'm expecting the first 6 digits to be in the format yymmdd and adding the '19' to form a ccyymmdd date string. Not all the strings conform to this format though, hence the isdate() check which isn't working as I expected it to. I don't know how to find value of the offending string?

Comment: try trycast like this `TRY_CAST('12/31/2010' AS date)`

Comment: you can see the offending string as well,isdate is dependant on SET DATEFORMAT and SET LANGUAGE settings

Comment: Thanks for your help. TRY_CAST isn't found as a function?

Comment: its available from 2012

Comment: weird, I'm working with 2014....

Comment: what is your database compatabilty level .check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624262/understanding-compatibility-level-in-sql-server

Comment: Compatability level = 120, so it should be working if I understand this correctly. I tried moving this discussion to chat but I don't have the right credentials, don't know if you have?

Comment: Can you paste the exact error,you got for try cast

Comment: Uhmm, OK now it's working :), how can I mark your comment as an answer? For interest sake: the offending string started with PM3299. Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with SQL Server 2012, you can use <kbd>TRY_CAST</kbd> to ensure conversions won't fail, but return `null` instead.

In your case,its some thing like below

```
TRY_CAST('19' + LEFT(somestring, 6) AS DATE)
```